# Nested table primary and foreign key in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, nested-table

I'm trying to add a primary and foreign key to a nested table, struggling to know how.

This is what I have;

```
create or replace type profile as object 
(
id VARCHAR2(10), --- Suppose to be Primary Key
userID VARCHAR2(10) --- Suppose to be Foreign Key for user table
);

create or replace type profile_nest as table of profile;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE user_t UNDER group_T
(profile profile_nest_ty,);


CREATE TABLE user OF user_t
(id NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
nested table profile store as profile_storage_tbl;
```

Now the problem is this part, trying to do a foreign key -

```
alter table profile_storage_tbl add CONSTRAINT fk_userID FOREIGN KEY (userID)
REFERENCES user(id);
```

Gives this error -

> *Error starting at line 3 in command:
>   alter table profile_storage_tbl add CONSTRAINT fk_userID FOREIGN KEY (userID)
>   REFERENCES user(id)
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-30730: referential constraint not allowed on nested table column
>   30730. 00000 -  "referential constraint not allowed on nested table column"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to define a referential constraint on a nested
>              table column.
>   *Action:   Do not specify referential constraints on nested table columns.*

Answer (score 1):

**Either** you create 2 separate tables `profile_storage_tbl` and `user` with a foreign key between them **or** you create `profile_storage_tbl` as a nested table within the `user` table.  It doesn't make sense to try to do both.  (In fact nested tables make little sense to me, period - but that's another matter!)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I have created profile_storage_tbl as a nested table in user table. The issue is, I have another table that I will need to have a relation with the profile_storage_tbl nested table. So I need to know how I'm going to add constraints.

Answer (score 1):

It is just as the exception text says, creating a foreign key constraint on nested table columns is not allowed (Oracle 11).

There is sort of a workaround described here: http://ksun-oracle.blogspot.com/2011/05/foreign-key-on-nested-table.html. But there is no guarantee, that this would work on the next oracle release.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to ask, can nested tables have primary keys or unique identifiers for each row?

Comment: Yes to primary key constraint and unique constraint. The latter you can see in the linked article. You can see an example for a primary key here:http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2318607631616#4040376500346333254

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scene oracle will create two tables profile_storage_tbl and user whereas profile_storage_tbl has a foreign key on user.
You can do that on your own, with the advatage to have better control over the releations (also to other tables).